# How to use Address function to write in the found cell? Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to find a specific cell based on variable data. Currently, I'm using the "address" function to give the name of the cell, in this case Q10, and then filling it manually. Is there a way to make it so the cell will be filled or have something written in it automatically?

Worksheet, green highlight for the cell found with formula, blue highlight is that cell on the sheet

[image: Worksheet, green highlight for the cell found with formula, blue highlight is that cell on the sheet]

Comment: Can you post the ADDRESS formula?

Comment: =ADDRESS(14-E13,E12+9).  The 14- and +9 are just for positioning it relative to the grid

Comment: Yes you can with VBA. If you are looking for a formula in Q10 that will calculate something based on data from elsewhere in your spreadsheet that can be done too. But that will probably require formulas in all of your grid, probably pointing to the whole data set and not what looks like a subset of the dataset to do one computation.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to start researching how to do that in VBA? I'm very new to using it and could use a topic or starting point

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use the ADDRESS formula here.

You want to format a cell based on the numbers in cells E12 and E13.

For that, you can use conditional formatting.

Set up a rule like this:

[image]

[image]

Your current implementation appears to use the decimals in cells E12 and E13 to create an address of row and column numbers, though it highlights coordinate (8,4) and your data, when rounded, would be (9,4).

This rule will place the highlight in coordinate (9,4). If you don't want that, then adjust the rule definition accordingly.

As you can see, when the coordinates change, the highlight moves.

[image]

While this will probably do the job for what you've set up so far, since you're using coordinates, perhaps an appropriately labelled x/y scatter plot would be easier?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

1. Select the Range **J5:AC13**, go to **Home**- **Conditional Formatting**- **New Rule...**
   [image]
2. Select the **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**- enter the formula and Format cells:

   =ADDRESS(14-$E$13,$E$12+9)="$"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")&"$"&ROW()

[image]

[image]